# accessing private variable from member function in PHP

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have derived a class from `Exception`, basically like so:

```
class MyException extends Exception {

    private $_type;

    public function type() {
        return $this->_type; //line 74
    }

    public function __toString() {

        include "sometemplate.php";
        return "";

    }

}
```

Then, I derived from `MyException` like so:

```
class SpecialException extends MyException {

    private $_type = "superspecial";

}
```

If I `throw new SpecialException("bla")` from a function, catch it, and go `echo $e`, then the `__toString` function should load a template, display that, and then not actually return anything to echo.

This is basically what's in the template file

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->type(); ?>class">

    <p> <?php echo $this->message; ?> </p>

</div>
```

in my mind, this should definitely work. However, I get the following error when an exception is thrown and I try to display it:

> **Fatal error**: Cannot access private property SpecialException::$_type in **C:\path\to\exceptions.php** on line **74**

Can anyone explain why I am breaking the rules here? Am I doing something horribly witty with this code? Is there a much more idiomatic way to handle this situation? The point of the `$_type` variable is (as shown) that I want a different div class to be used depending on the type of exception caught.

Comment: As I wrote down there: It is very very very ugly to let __toString() return an empty string. I really can't see ANY usecase for such stuff.

Comment: The empty return of __toString() for an Exception is even more doubtful.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Name the variable protected:

```
* Public: anyone either inside the class or outside can access them
* Private: only the specified class can access them. Even subclasses will be denied access.
* Protected: only the specified class and subclasses can access them
```

Comment: Note: In PHP `protected` means that your parents can access them, too.

Comment: alright, I did this -- but now I can't use `$this->message` -- no error, it just displays nothing... why?

Comment: nevermind, I was setting `$message` in the parent constructor instead of `$this->message`. Also, I realized I provided no actual implementation details of how I was setting the message in the first place. My bad

Answer (score 44):

just an example how to access private property

```
<?php
class foo {
    private $bar = 'secret';
}
$obj = new foo;


if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0)
{

      $myClassReflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
      $secret = $myClassReflection->getProperty('bar');
      $secret->setAccessible(true);
      echo $secret->getValue($obj);
}
else 
{
    $propname="\0foo\0bar";
    $a = (array) $obj;
    echo $a[$propname];
}
```

Comment: How can I do the "else" thing you have here for the setter?

Answer (score 13):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441769/1889685

---

As of *PHP 5.4*, you can use the predefined `Closure` class to bind a method/property of a class to a delta functions that has access even to private members.

[The Closure class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

For example we have a class with a private variable and we want to access it outside the class:

```php
class Foo {
    private $bar = "Foo::Bar";
}
```

**PHP 5.4+**

```php
$foo = new Foo;
$getFooBarCallback = function() {
    return $this->bar;
};

$getFooBar = $getFooBarCallback->bindTo($foo, 'Foo');
echo $getFooBar(); // Prints Foo::Bar
```

As of PHP 7, you can use the new `Closure::call` method, to bind any method/property of an obect to a callback function, even for private members:

**PHP 7+**

```php
$foo = new Foo;
$getFooBar = function() {
    return $this->bar;
};

echo $getFooBar->call($foo); // Prints Foo::Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this way by using \Closure :

```php
$reader = function ($object, $property) {
    $value = \Closure::bind(function () use ($property) {
         return $this->$property;
    }, $object, $object)->__invoke();

    return $value;
};

$myClass = new MyClass();
$property = $reader($myClass, 'yourProperty');
echo $property; // will display the value of property
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the access to protected. Private means that it can only be accessed from within it's own class and can't be inherited. Protected allows it to be inhherited but it still can't be accessed directly from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) documentation, buried in a comment is:

> // We can redeclare the public and protected method, but not private

You should make it `protected` to do what you're trying to do.

Incidentally, it looks like you're just setting it to be the class name - you could just use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/get_class):

```
<div class="<?php echo get_class($this); ?>class">
```

Comment: sure, but then if I changed the (php) class name I'd have to change the (css) class name, and also, if I want to use more information in the exception template file, I would probably add it the same way I added the "type" property.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed change the accessmodifier to `protected` when you'e builing inheritance classes.

One extra point though; don't use `return "";` but just use `return;`

Comment: your extra point causes a fatal error, I tried that already -- `__toString()` **MUST** return a string

Comment: Ah I'm sorry! I looked over your __toString function.. just saw you were returning 'nothing'. You're absolutely right!

Comment: It is very very very ugly to let __toString() return an empty string. I really can't see ANY usecase for such stuff. But you're right, __toString() must return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot access $this outside of a class. 
Instead, need to call an instance of the class. 
Then, access a function within the class which will return the message.

Comment: Well, a programmer would give a code snippet to clear things up. Right? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a guide. Thank you.