# How can a PHP class that extends another inherit a private function?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I am trying to extend a PHP class without rewriting the whole thing. Here is an example:

```
<?
$a = new foo();
print $a->xxx();
$b = new bar();
print $b->xxx();

class foo {
  const something = 10;

  public function xxx() {
    $this->setSomething();
    return $this->something;
  }

  private function setSomething() {
    $this->something = self::something;
  }
}

class bar extends foo {

  public function xxx() {
    $this->setSomething();
    $this->something++;
    return $this->something;
  }

}
?>
```

However when I run the script I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to private method foo::setSomething() from context 'bar' in test.php on line 23
```

It would seem that bar is not inheriting the private function setSomething(). How would I fix this without modifying the foo class?

Comment: You can't change `setSomething()` to `protected` ?

Comment: As I stated above, the foo class is not to be modified. How else can I do this?

Comment: You use the right tool for the job, that is, make it `protected`.

Comment: I understand your point however I do not have acces to change the original class. Perhaps I oversimplified the example. The original class is from another file that is merely included with require().

Comment: In that case the author don't want it to be available in subclass. Or didnt think about in design phase. So this is a by design rule of that parent class.

Comment: Then contact the original author and make clear that you need to extend the class.

Comment: Oh well, I was trying to do something that is clearly beyond the original design scope. I would hate to say they didn't think about it, I don't think they could have anticipated what I have in mind.

Comment: Just write your own method, if you can't set the original class's method to `protected`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar` is *inheriting* the function alright, but it can't call it. That's the whole point of `private` methods, only the declaring class can call them.

Comment: So I would have to explicitly redefine setSomething() in my bar class?

Comment: Yes, that's the *sane* method to do this.

Comment: Better method is to use protected in the parent class ;) that way it stays private from outside, but "child" class can access it.

Answer (score 15):

**No**, you can not fix this without modifying the foo class. Because **an inherited class can not access parent class's private members**. It's a very basic [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) rule.

Declare `setSomething()` as `protected`. It'll be solved.

See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: As I stated above, the foo class is not to be modified. How else can I do this?

Comment: You can not do it as long as maintain oop.

Comment: So private inheritance in C++ is not real OOP? I do not agree.

Answer (score 8):

Private members are not inheritable, you can not use them in sub class. They are not accessible outside the class.

You must need to make that function as protected or public. Protected members are accessible to that class and for the inherited class. So, your best bet is to make that function Protected.

Comment: As I stated above, the foo class is not to be modified. How else can I do this?

Comment: @KennethVogt: You don't have choices here.

Answer (score 4):

Try reflection

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Also:

[Call private methods and private properties from outside a class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738663/call-private-methods-and-private-properties-from-outside-a-class-in-php)

Comment: Wow, that scared me into not getting too fancy. Nice info though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
class bar extends foo {

    public function xxx() {
      $this->something = parent::xxx();
      $this->something++;
      return $this->something;
    }
}
```

Note the **parent::xxx();** is public, so it should work... even though it looks like a static call.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the original class, there is no way for the inherited class to directly call `private` methods of the parent class.