# How can I access a private variable in a class without changing its visibility

Tags: php

I am wondering is it possible for me to access the `_staff_id` variable without me having to change the declaration to public (I have access to change this but its not my code and im assuming it was made private for a reason, however i am still tasked with getting this information)

```
MyObject Object
(

    [_staff_id:private] => 43

)
```

Comment: You can't access it from outside of the class, unless you class has a public getter method.... that's the whole point of private

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing private variable from member function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762135/accessing-private-variable-from-member-function-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a public `get` function. E.g.:

```
class MyObject {
    private _staff_id = 43

    public function get($field) {
        return $this->$field;
    }
}
$myObject = new MyObject;
$staff_id = $myObject->get('_staff_id');
```

This allows you to access the variable without the ability to overwrite its value.