# Read the Firestore Geopoint Object in PHP

Tags: php, object, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble reading this object I'm getting from my Firestore document's Geopoint.

I didn't find any documentation as how to use the PHP Framework to read this geopoint (as its possible in swift).

The full array looks like that:

```php
print_r($barDetails);
```

```
Array 
( 
[icone_img] => xqSUmb8kCWIanQj3okaf 
[geopoint] => Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint Object 
( 
[latitude:Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint:private] => 43.697092 [longitude:Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint:private] => 7.274421 
) 
[header_img] => SGYXf7DIYRvvpqLIEZr4 
[nom] => La Lupita 
[styles_ids] => Array 
( 
[0] => fKMTFTgAvhHN9D5e7n3p 
) 
[adresse] => 9 Rue de la Préfecture, 06300 Nice 
[description] => Aenean dictum lectus est, non fringilla enim tempus et. Nam dapibus elit in lobortis sagittis. Sed quis metus in lacus congue tempus at quis mi. 
)
```

If I do:

```php
print_r($barDetails['geopoint']);
```

I get this object, which I'm unable to read in order to get the latitude and longitude separately:

```
Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint Object 
( 
[latitude:Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint:private] => 43.697092
[longitude:Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint:private] => 7.274421 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **To access an object property you have to use `->`.**

`echo $object->property;`

---

**In this case you want to access the latitude and longitude properties of the `geopoint` object.**

> **Latitude:**

`echo $barDetails['geopoint']->latitude;`

> **Longitude:**

`echo $barDetails['geopoint']->longitude;`

---

> **Important. Please remember that private properties can only be accessed by the class that defines the property. Therefore, the above will only work if your properties are set to public. Otherwise, you will need to create a method in your class to allow access to your private object properties.**

More info can be found in this other **[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762135/accessing-private-variable-from-member-function-in-php).**

---

### Update

> **For private class members, you will need a "getter" method or function inside your class that returns the values for latitude and longitude to allow access to those values outside the class.**
>
> **Latitude:**

```
echo $barDetails['geopoint']->latitude();
```

> **Longitude:**

```
echo $barDetails['geopoint']->longitude();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately trying to access `echo $barDetails['geopoint']->latitude;` breaks my page (plain blank).

Also, i'm receiving those datas straight from my Firestore storage, so i am not sure how to adapt to the private property's issue ..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i looked at it the wrong way. `Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint` has simple functions called `latitude()` and `longitude()` which can be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-core/blob/master/src/GeoPoint.php).

````php
/**
     * Get the latitude
     *
     * Example:
     * ```
     * $latitude = $point->latitude();
     * ```
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function latitude()
    {
        $this->checkContext('latitude', func_get_args());
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Get the longitude
     *
     * Example:
     * ```
     * $longitude = $point->longitude();
     * ```
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function longitude()
    {
        $this->checkContext('longitude', func_get_args());
        return $this->longitude;
    }
````

So `barDetails['geopoint']->latitude();` did the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked. Notice that since latitude and longitude are private members in your class, a "getter" method is being used to return the values of those object properties. Please if my answer helped you clarify your issue, please consider accepting or upvoting my answer for better visibility to other community users. Thank you.