# Access variable outside for loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to access a variable in a loop outside the for a loop.

I have defined the variable outside the class function as a private variable like this.

```
private $counter;
```

Then inside the function, I have used it like this.

```
public function counter_loop(){
  for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
  $this->counter++;
}
return $this->counter;
}
```

But getting an error saying $counter is undefined.

Comment: its in controller ? it working without error ??

Comment: Yes in the same controller. But it's quite confusing for me since not working

Comment: with your code i just checked , for me its return 100 ...... !?

Comment: Since `$counter` isn't used in your pasted code, the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: are you trying from sub classes ? just read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762135/accessing-private-variable-from-member-function-in-php

Comment: It depends on how you're trying to print the $counter variable. 
`echo $object->counter_loop()` will print `100` (where `$object` is an instance of the class). Show how you're trying to access the variable in your code.

Comment: are you sure you are not just making a spelling mistake while using the variable name ? this happens you know...
coz for me its also reverting  100

Answer (score 0):

`$counter` is undefined because there isn't an initial value. Try this:

```
private $counter = 0;
```